# Network not working after moving the virtual server

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking

I moved my server from one virtual server instance to another instance, exporting the image and importing it to the new server. Everything is working fine, except the network. The new server tries to use the IP address of the old server, so I cannot connect to the new server.
Executing  `ip a` shows the old ip. If I run `dhclient -r eht 0` and `dhclient eth0` it works. `ip a` shows the new ip and I can connect to my server. But when I restart my server, I have the same problem again.
So in `/etc/network/interface.d` I updated the old IPv4 and IPv6 to the new ones. When I restart the server now, `ip a` now shows the correct IP addresses. But the network is still only working after running `dhclient -r eth0` and `dhclient eth0`.

Edit:
I'm using debian buster.
Outgoing connections do not work either.
`/etc/network/interface.d` now contains this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address newIPv4/22
    dns-nameservers 46.38.225.230 46.38.252.230 2a03:4000:8000::fce6
    gateway 185.233.104.1
    post-up ifup eth0:1


auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet6 static
    address newIPv6/64
    gateway fe80::1
```

Comment: When asking about virtual servers you should give more information about your environment. It could be VMware, Xen, KVM, or a hosted provider (and they would be the ones to ask networking questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the middle section of your `interface` file to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up ifup eth0:1
```

This will cause it to use DHCP upon startup.

Comment: That's working, thanks!